# Getting default printer change notification using c++ in Windows service

Tags: windows, service, printing, notifications, default

I need to tap default printer change notification, is it possible?

My scenario is that I want to execute a command whenever default printer is changed in window. What my command does is, it just takes default printer information from registry and save it in HKLM.

So, I have a service for this. Using this service, how can i tap notifications whenever a default printer is changed. I am using C++.

Answer (score 0):

From a regular application, I would listen for a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message and then call [`GetDefaultPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if the default printer has actually changed.

I don't know if you can watch for that message from a service.  The default printer can be a per-user setting, so your service would have to be running as that user rather than as Local System.

Answer (score 0):

Intercept message WM_WININICHANGE, then get the new printer:

```
PRINTDLGW *pd;
pd = (PRINTDLGW *)malloc(sizeof(PRINTDLGW));
pd->lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGW);
pd->hDevMode = NULL;
pd->hDevNames = NULL;
pd->Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT;
PrintDlgW(pd);
```